# MoveFile function leading to a null destination

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

When using the Windows MoveFile() function.. where does the file go if the below occurs?:

```
CString oldFile = _T("C:\\Dirs\\Programs\\Prog.txt");
CString newDestination; // NOT INITIALIZED 

MoveFile(oldFile, newDestination);
```

This accidently happened to me and now I can't find the file anywhere..is it possible that the file has been deleted?

Comment: I tried your code. its not deleting any file from my system. once check return value of `MoveFile(oldFile, newDestination); `

Comment: Thx Himanshu... I just found the file... it turns out the function returned the file to the root drive... which in my case is C:\ ....

Comment: For what it is worth a CString has a default constructor and is initialized to an empty string.  Simply declaring an int, for example, is uninitialized and would have an unspecified value.